# Android / Java restart background of button

Tags: android, button

I have a button, and the change the color, and I want a button to restart the color, size, etc of the buttons the user changed.

I tried with this:

```
button1.setBackgroundColor("@drawable/margin");
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: use button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.margin) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.margin);`